# Is TileMill as a service restricted to PNG? Or is JPEG an option?

Tags: tilemill, mapbox, mbtiles, tile-server

Is TileMill as a service restricted to PNG? Or is JPEG an option?

I setup TIleMill as a service as documented here:

https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/ubuntu-service/

Tiles are rendering locally e.g:

http://127.0.0.1:20008/tile/q/10/937/596.png

I've tried changing the extension with no luck.

I realise I can export as mbtiles and use TileStache or similar but thought I would as the question.

Comment: JPEG does not seem to be an option for exporting tiles from Tilemill. Have a look at this: https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/crashcourse/exporting/

Comment: Yes it does allow JPEG for export  but Im asking if it can serve JPEG tilds dynamically with its server service feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I have just discovered that the extension stays as PNG but the image is rendered as JPEG as selected in Project Settings. [image]

Answer (score 1):

You can change the image format of the tiles you want to export by

1. First opening the "project settings" menu by clicking on the wrench in the upper righthand corner and then
2. Select which the image format for your tiles from the `format` dropdown menu

Comment: Doesn't that just change the format in stored in mbtiles? The tiles served dynamically still seem to be png.

Comment: You were right, but extension stays the same. See my answer.